# Рандом по процентам в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Сделал рандом по процентам через weights, но мне кажется это неправильно. синий = 46% красный = 46% зеленый = 8%. Я думаю что этот рандом слишком предсказуемый

```
color = random.choices(['синий', 'красный', 'зеленый'], weights=[46, 46, 8])[0]
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под предсказуемостью?

Comment: @mkkik, повторение комбинаций. Выпадает 2 синих 2 красных почти всегда.

Comment: _Выпадает 2 синих 2 красных_ при выборке из 4? Ну так вы сами задали такие веса.

Comment: тоесть я хочу чтобы было например стрик из красных или синих. потому что идет просто 2 синих 2 красных. я бы хотел чтобы это было рандомнее

Comment: "Почти всегда" - это сколько именно раз из скольки испытаний? Я прогнал ваш код 100000 раз и всего в 43% с копейками случаев оно выдаёт такой же цвет. как на предыдущем ходе. Согласитесь, меньше половины - это совсем не то же, что "почти всегда".

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы было чередование, вы можете запоминать сколько-то последних результатов и менять вероятности в соответствии с этим (вплоть до того, что можно вообще ставить нулевую вероятность тому цвету, который выпал в последний раз). Но это не будет "рандомнее", на самом деле как раз наоборот.